# Check the open FD limit for a given process in Linux

Tags: linux, scripting, operating-system, limit, file-descriptor

I recently had a Linux process which “leaked” file descriptors: It opened them and didn't properly close some of them.

If I had monitored this, I could tell – in advance – that the process was reaching its limit.

Is there a nice, Bash or Python way to check the FD usage ratio for a given process in a Ubuntu Linux system?

**EDIT:**

I now know how to check how many open file descriptors are there; I only need to know **how many file descriptors are allowed for a process**. Some systems (like Amazon EC2) don't have the `/proc/pid/limits` file.

Comment: What Amazon EC2 Linux OS are you using with no /proc/pid/limits? It is available on RHEL 5. If you want a solution for a different OS then tell us which one.

Comment: I have an Ubuntu EC2 server, but I'm interested with a more general solution that would apply for a wide variety of Linux Distros.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Count the entries in `/proc/<pid>/fd/`.  The hard and soft limits applying to the process can be found in `/proc/<pid>/limits`.

Comment: I think, this method may be more elegant than polling lsof

Comment: Yes, but some processes - like web servers - are asking for a larger quota using ulimit, and I want to monitor their FD usage.

Comment: No process will be allowed to raise its quota above the hardlimit, which can be viewed with `ulimit -Hn`.

Comment: limits entry in proc is available since 2.6.24. A pity for some of us living in older kernels :( .

Answer (score 34):

The only interfaces provided by the Linux kernel to get resource limits are [`getrlimit()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) and [`/proc/`*pid*`/limits`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html).  `getrlimit()` can only get resource limits of the calling process.  `/proc/`*pid*`/limits` allows you to get the resource limits of any process with the same user id, and is available on RHEL 5.2, RHEL 4.7, Ubuntu 9.04, and any distribution with a 2.6.24 or later kernel.

If you need to support older Linux systems then you will have to get the process itself to call `getrlimit()`.  Of course the easiest way to do that is by modifying the program, or a library that it uses.  If you are running the program then you could use `LD_PRELOAD` to load your own code into the program.  If none of those are possible then you could attach to the process with gdb and have it execute the call within the process.  You could also do the same thing yourself using `ptrace()` to attach to the process, insert the call in its memory, etc., however this is very complicated to get right and is not recommended.

With appropriate privileges, the other ways to do this would involve looking through kernel memory, loading a kernel module, or otherwise modifying the kernel, but I am assuming that these are out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

to see the top 20 file handle using processes:

```
for x in `ps -eF| awk '{ print $2 }'`;do echo `ls /proc/$x/fd 2> /dev/null | wc -l` $x `cat /proc/$x/cmdline 2> /dev/null`;done | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```

the output is in the format file handle count, pid, cmndline for process

example output

```
701 1216 /sbin/rsyslogd-n-c5
169 11835 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
164 13621 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
161 13622 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
161 13618 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have some warning :
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
799 3708 /usr/sbin/mysqld
469 12904 pveproxy worker
454 18544 pveproxy worker
442 5236 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write script which periodically call `lsof -p {PID}` on given pid.

Comment: lsof gives a lot of irrelevant entries (like shared libraries in the memory).

Comment: I guess, it doesn't matter whether fds are connected to shared-memory libs or to 'usual' application-specific files -- these fds still use their share.

Comment: No, those are not open file descriptors and do not count toward the file descriptor limit.

Comment: Furthermore, lsof does not state the FD limitations per process.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for bash/python methods.  ulimit would be the best bash approach (short of munging through `/proc/$pid/fd` and the like by hand).  For python, you could use the resource module.

```
import resource

print(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE))
```

> ```
> $ python test.py
>
> (1024, 65536)
> ```

[`resource.getrlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.getrlimit) corresponds to the `getrlimit` call in a C program.  The results represent the current and maximum values for the requested resource.  In the above example, the current (soft) limit is 1024.  The values are typical defaults on Linux systems these days.

Comment: resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE: The maximum number of open file descriptors for the current process, and I would like to get the results of ANOTHER process, not myself.

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 6 and below (anything using GCC 3), you may find that adjusting the kernel limits does not resolve the issue. This is because there is a [FD_SETSIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976388/increasing-limit-of-fd-setsize-and-select) value that is set at compile time in use by GCC. For this, you will need to increase the value and then re-compile the process.

Also, you may find that you are leaking file descriptors due to [known issues in libpthread](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/libpthread.html) if you are using that library. This call was integrated into GCC in GCC 4 / CentOS7 / RHEL 7 and this seems to have fixed the threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

Python wrapper using the excellent psutil package:

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username', 'num_fds']):
    try:
        soft, hard = p.rlimit(psutil.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
        cur = p.info['num_fds']
        usage = int(cur / soft * 100)
        print('{:>2d}% {}/{}/{}'.format(
            usage,
            p.info['pid'],
            p.info['username'],
            p.info['name'],
            ))
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        pass
```