# Increasing FD_SETSIZE

Tags: select, glibc

I need to increase the FD_SETSIZE value from `1024` to `4096`. I know it'd be better to use `poll()/epoll()` but I want to understand what are pros/cons. The main question is: have I to recompile `glibc`? I read several thread where the change of .h after changing `FD_SETSIZE` works recompiling only the user application. Reading the `glibc` code (and the kernel too), actually it seems to me that if I want to use select(), FD_* macro and so on, I have to recompile all because the size of `fd_set` is changed. At this point I have to recompile *all* not only my application because if in the system there is an another "common" application that uses select and friends, I could have problem. Am I right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing limit of FD\_SETSIZE and select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976388/increasing-limit-of-fd-setsize-and-select)

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you do not have  to recompile glibc. It would be sufficient to use come up with your own version of `<sys/select.h>` that has a larger `fd_set_t`, but is otherwise compatible. It will magically work because the `select` function receives the largest file descriptor (plus one), so it can figure out the set sizes. The other functions and macros are either inline or do not care about the actual set size.

It's still a bad idea, so you really should be using `poll` or `epoll` instead.

In the past, some libcs supported defining `FD_SETSIZE` before including `<sys/select.h>` to obtain a larger set size, but I don't think support for that was ever part of mainline glibc.