# Behavior of Select and FD_SET When Fd is Bigger than 1024

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, select, glibc

As far as I know, select only supports no more than 1024 sockets. But a process can own 65535 sockets which means most of the socket numbers are bigger than 1024, so I have three questions:

Q1. What will happen if passing socket numbers bigger than 1024 to FD_SET()？
Q2. What will happen if passing fd_set whose socket numbers are all bigger than 1024 to    select()?
Q3. On Linux Fedora with kernel 2.6.8, x86 64bit, will exceptions be thrown in Q1 and Q2?

Comment: IMHO, if you have that many sockets, you really should consider epoll rather than select, it scales way better than select.

Comment: You could use some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) library like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://libev.schmorp.de/‎)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing limit of FD\_SETSIZE and select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976388/increasing-limit-of-fd-setsize-and-select)

Comment: In my case, it gave back the wrong "ready to read" fd, and my (single-threaded program ended up blocked indefinitely on a read()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `fd_set` is an array of bits, only manipulated with `FD_*` macros because C doesn't have a "bit" type. (The type is officially opaque, and could be implemented a different way - in fact winsock does implement it differently - but all unix-like OSes use the array of bits.)

So this code:

```
fd_set my_fds;
....
FD_SET(1024, &my_fds);
```

has the same problem as this code:

```
char my_fds[1024];
....
my_fds[1024] = 1;
```

assuming `FD_SETSIZE` is 1024.

You will be overwriting whatever comes after the `fd_set` in memory, causing a segfault if you're lucky, more subtle errors if you're not.

Comment: I don't think this answer is particularly relevant to the question... the OP wants to know how to handle *more than* 1024 sockets...

Comment: @Nim the questions are all "what will happen if I do this", not "what should I do instead" - I chose to answer what was asked instead of skipping ahead to an anticipated followup question.