# What does select do when nfds is greater than length of bit array in fd_set? Is it possible?

Tags: c, linux, unix, select

```
int select(int nfds, 
       fd_set *readfds, 
       fd_set *writefds, 
       fd_set *exceptfds, 
       struct timeval *timeout);
```

Given fd_set is 1024 in length. What if the fd we want to monitor is 2048? What does select do when this happens? Will it happen at all?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7976388/694576

Answer (score 2):

According to [the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html), if `nfds` is larger than `FD_SETSIZE`, `select()` will return -1 and set `errno` to EINVAL.

In some implementations (including on Linux systems), it will instead write to bits outside the `fd_set` structure, potentially corrupting memory in your application. (The intent is to allow applications to use larger `fd_set` structures, but the effect is often to cause applications to crash as soon as they try to use more than 1024 file descriptors.)

To work with more than 1024 file descriptors, you will need to use an API other than `select()`. These APIs are often system-specific; one platform-independent option to consider is the [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) library, which provides a set of useful abstractions for highly concurrent applications.