# Is there a POSIX-way to extend fd_set?

Tags: select, posix

Recent POSIX tells me that an `fd_set` is a structure capable of holding up to `FD_SETSIZE` fd's.

On Linux and glibc I find that `FD_SETSIZE` is 1024, the default (soft) `RLIMIT_NOFILE` is also 1024, and `sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)` is also 1024.

I can increase the `RLIMIT_NOFILE`, but I cannot find anything in POSIX which tells me how to create an "extended `fd_set`" to match the new maximum number of fd's.

It looks like older POSIX used to specify that the `fd_set` contained an array `fds_bits`, and it would then be safe to create an "extended `fd_set`" as some multiple of `sizeof(fds_bits[0])` (suitably aligned).

I find that various BSDs allow me to set `FD_SETSIZE`, provided that's done early enough.  That doesn't seem to work for glibc and Linux :-(

It seems that `NFDBIT` is perhaps what I need -- which is a BSD thing, which glibc will give me under `__USE_MISC`.  There is also an `fd_mask` type, where the bit vector is `fd_mask xxx[xx]`.

What I cannot find is a POSIX way to do this.  Have I missed something ?

I know that for thousands of fd's I should probably be using `epoll` or `kqueue`... but I feel there should be a standard way of extending `fd_set` beyond `FD_SETSIZE`.

Comment: `FD_SETSIZE` and `RLIMIT_NOFILE` are orthogonal.

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7976388 . I would really suggest that you use epoll/kqueue though (whether directly or through a wrapper library).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: indeed... and it's a trap for the unwary -- just because some form of 'open' has returned an `fd` doesn't mean you can `FD_SET(fd, xxx)` :-(