# Thrift: Too many open files

Tags: sockets, thrift, thrift-protocol

Following error I am getting when I run thrift services

```
Thrift: Wed Dec 11 18:03:14 2013 thriftServerEventHandler: accept() Too many open files
Thrift: Wed Dec 11 18:03:14 2013 thriftServerEventHandler: accept() Too many open files
Thrift: Wed Dec 11 18:03:14 2013 thriftServerEventHandler: accept() Too many open files
Thrift: Wed Dec 11 18:03:14 2013 thriftServerEventHandler: accept() Too many open files
Thrift: Wed Dec 11 18:03:14 2013 thriftServerEventHandler: accept() Too many open files
Thrift: Wed Dec 11 18:03:14 2013 thriftServerEventHandler: accept() Too many open files
```

Mt thrift server in c++ and using ThreadManager and php client with TFramedTransport

Comment: Assuming Linux: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880557/socket-accept-too-many-open-files and related answers?

Comment: But my problem is connection is not going beyond 500 without any concurrency ulimit is the later part

Comment: So what does `ulimit -a` say and how many FDs are in use? If in doubt, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356675/check-the-open-fd-limit-for-a-given-process-in-linux to find out the latter.