# How can I make poll() exit immediately in C on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, posix-api

I'm using the function *poll()* (I think it might be part of POSIX?) C function in my C++ class in order to get an event when a file changes. This seems to work just fine - but now I also want to be able to cause the function to exit immediately when I need to close the thread.

I researched this and came up with a couple of ideas that I tried - like trying to send a signal, but I couldn't figure out how to get this to work.

In the code below (which isn't 100% complete, but should have enough to illustrate the problem), I have a C++ class that starts a thread from the constructor and wants to clean up that thread in the destructor. The thread calls *poll()* which returns when the file changes, and then it informs the delegate object. The monitoring thread loops until the **FileMonitor** object indicates it can quit (using a method that returns a bool).

In the destructor, what I would **like** to do is flip the bool, then do something that causes *poll()* to exit immediately, and then call *pthread_join()*. So, any ideas on how I can make *poll()* exit immediately?

This code is targeted towards Linux (specifically debian), but I'm also working on it on a Mac. Ideally it the poll() API should work basically the same.

```
void * manage_fm(void *arg)
{
    FileMonitor * theFileMonitor = (FileMonitor*)arg;
    FileMonitorDelegate * delegate;

    unsigned char c;
    int fd = open(theFileMonitor->filepath2monitor(), O_RDWR);

    int count;

    ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &count);
    for (int i=0;i<count;++i) {
       read(fd, &c, 1);
    }

    struct pollfd poller;
    poller.fd = fd;
    poller.events = POLLPRI;


    while (theFileMonitor->continue_managing_thread()) {
        delegate = theFileMonitor->delegate;
        if (poll(&poller, 1, -1) > 0) {
            (void) read(fd, &c, 1);
            if (delegate) {
                delegate->fileChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

FileMonitor::FileMonitor( )
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mon_mutex, NULL);

    manage_thread = true;

    pthread_mutex_lock (&mon_mutex);

    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, manage_fm, this);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pin_mutex);

}

FileMonitor::~FileMonitor()
{
    manage_thread = false;

    // I would like to do something here to force the "poll" function to return immediately.

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
}

bool FileMonitor::continue_managing_thread()
{
    return manage_thread;
}

const char * FileMonitor::filepath2monitor()
{
    return "/some/example/file";
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you didn't include a bunch on unnecessary code in your question. On top of that, some code required to understand this is even missing. Sorry, that doesn't make a good question.

Answer (score 3):

Add a pipe to your file monitor class and switch your poll to take both your original file descriptor and the pipe's read descriptor to poll on.  When you want to wake up your file monitor class for it to check for exit, send a byte through the pipe's write descriptor, that will wake up your thread.

If you have a large number of these file monitors, there's the possibility you could hit the maximum number of file descriptors for a process (See [Check the open FD limit for a given process in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356675/check-the-open-fd-limit-for-a-given-process-in-linux) for details, on my system it's 1024 soft, 4096 hard).  You could have multiple monitor classes share a single pipe if you don't mind them all waking up at once to check their exit indicator.

Answer (score -2):

You should use a pthread [condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) inside (and just before) the `poll`-ing loop, and have the other thread calling [pthread_cond_signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html)

You might consider the [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self trick (e.g. have one thread [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) a byte -perhaps just before [pthread_cond_signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html)- to a pipe [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)-ed by another thread who would [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) the *same* pipe). See also [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [calling Qt functions from Unix signal handlers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html). Both could inspire you.

With that pipe-to-self trick, assuming you do `poll` for reading that pipe, the `poll` will return. Of course some other thread would have done a `write` on the *same* pipe before.

See also [Philippe Chaintreuil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25692615/841108), he suggests a similar idea.

Comment: That won't cause poll() to exit.

Comment: It will cause the poll to exit