# Unable to create socket so as to call to my asterisk server?

Tags: linux, sockets, asterisk, sysctl

When i call to asterisk ,  asterisk give me a CONGESTION status. When I check my log , it was given following warning :

```
[Mar 17 13:33:03] WARNING[657] acl.c: Cannot create socket
[Mar 17 13:33:03] ERROR[657] rtp.c: Unable to allocate socket: Too many open files
[Mar 17 13:33:03] ERROR[657] rtp.c: Unable to allocate socket: Too many open files
[Mar 17 13:33:03] WARNING[657] chan_sip.c: Unable to create RTP audio and video session: Too many open files

[Mar 17 13:33:32] WARNING[657] channel.c: Channel allocation failed: Can't create alert pipe!
[Mar 17 13:33:32] WARNING[657] chan_sip.c: Unable to allocate AST channel structure for SIP channel
[Mar 17 13:33:32] NOTICE[657] chan_sip.c: Unable to create/find SIP channel for this INVITE
```

I have given high ulimit value but still problem arises. Can anyone know how this problem arises and how it could be stoped.

Comment: You have a socket or FD leak. You're not closing something you need to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try below two lines in command line

```
sudo asterisk -cvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvr
```

In asterisk CLI

```
ulimit descriptors 180839
```

Comment: Thanks  I was able to use *CLI>ulimit descriptors 999999 and now I can place 200 active calls using MOH and sipp

Answer (score 0):

1) check selinux/apparmor security settings

2) check limits for running proccess

[Check the open FD limit for a given process in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356675/check-the-open-fd-limit-for-a-given-process-in-linux)

3) check system wide limits for user asterisk(not root).

https://superuser.com/questions/810951/how-do-i-check-the-ulimit-for-another-user-and-change-open-files