# Kurento : NOT_ENOUGH_RESOURCES Exception

Tags: kurento

I have been working on customized code of one to many example, I came across this exception when there where more than 50 users joining the same room

`debug KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:488 processMessage()  Response: >{"error":{"code":40009,"data":{"type":"NOT_ENOUGH_RESOURCES"},"message":"Too many open files"},"id":5321,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}`

Is there any specific reason why I am getting `Too many open files` ?
Am I not closing the mediapipeline properly ?

Increasing the file descriptor count to one million also didn't help. Which I don't think increasing file descriptor count should be a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you have reached the file descriptors for the process. To check FDs for a process, check [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356675/check-the-open-fd-limit-for-a-given-process-in-linux). If you are not closing your pipelines and freeing up resources, it is most likely the case that you are reaching that limit.

Comment: okay, so in general how many fd's are required by one endpoint ? in case of one to many example what will happen if the receivers are more than 100users and 1 broadcaster should the fd count increase drastically. because in our case its going crazy and cpu is eaten up a lot

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Don't know the exact number, but you get 2-4 for sure just for media UDP ports open. Maybe internally some more are used, but don't have those numbers right now. Are you transcoding?