# AWS Lambda: IOException: Too many open files

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, file-descriptor

I deployed an AWS Lambda written in C#, and depending on the input I can see in the console the following error message (truncated):

```
{
  "Cause": "{\n  \"errorType\": \"IOException\",\n  \"errorMessage\": 
\"Too many open files : [...]at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectoryRecursive(String fullPath)
 "Error": "IOException",
  "ExecutionArn": [...]
```

I have a (somewhat?¹) good sense of what the error refer [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356675/check-the-open-fd-limit-for-a-given-process-in-linux), but I would like to *reproduce* it at least locally.

When I execute it using [AWS .NET Lambda test tool](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool) with the exact same input (JSON), I cannot trigger the exception. So I assume that my Windows 10 system is more forgiving about the number of file descriptors than the one on AWS side. So added a call to [_setmaxstdio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmaxstdio?view=msvc-170) in my Lambda code:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
public static extern int _setmaxstdio(int newMax);
```

And then in the main code I call:

```
int ret = _setmaxstdio(128);
```

I see a value of `128` being returned in the debugger, but again I cannot reproduce the issue locally using `AWS .NET Lambda test tool`. I picked 128 so that it is lower than the 1024 value described at:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution

How would one reproduce the exception locally ?

---

<sup>¹ I suspect that `Task.WhenAll` is being called on all 1024 threads, which is exactly reaching the limit of 1024 open file descriptors.</sup>

Comment: Are you executing it with the same exact payload locally?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will be more helpful, but the AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) will let you run your C# lambda code locally against AWS resources.  It also helps with deployment and additional infrastructure like S3 buckets or DyanmoDB tables.  This [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/dotnet/building-serverless-net-applications-with-aws-lambda-and-the-sam-cli/) is a good intro to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

File handle limits on Windows don't work the same way as fd limits on Linux. Try running your dotnet code in a Linux machine or container locally to reproduce the issue in a more representative environment. You can artificially set low limits using "ulimit -f 128", for example. You can find out more about Microsoft's official .NET container images and how to get started here: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-samples/

That said, are you sure you're closing all your file handles appropriately?  Anything that implements IDisposable should be used within a "using" statement or block to avoid leaking file handles and creeping toward that limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using